# In Push Notification Functionality and Cloud Messaging why the message is storing in certain format?

Tags: php, mysql, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

In the DataBase the message is stored like this.....

{"aps":{"alert":"dfgdfgdf"},"acme2":["bang","whiz"]}

Here am facing the problem While retrieving the data from DB i need to show only msg present in that alert but how can i retrieve that part from entire data stored in DB...

Comment: Looks like a JSON data, try reading JSON related materials. It depends on what you use, google search on how to extract what you want to get from that JSON.

Comment: That's the format used to send the payload of an Apple Push Notification, but you tagged your question as Google Cloud Messaging? So which one are you using? In what database is the message stored in this format? It doesn't have to be stored this way.